# @font not working in any browser everyting looks right

Tags: css, html, font-face, webfonts

I have read all relative answers on this site, as well as everywhere else on the www, but I still can't get my fonts to show up at all.  Paths are right, files are in the right place, font squirrel example works...

This is on my PC, and everything else works (Paths, images, links...) according yo everything I have read and seen it should work, here is my code in the CSS file:

```
    body {
    background: url('mcontentback.jpg') repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    min-width:497px;
    text-align:center;
    }
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bahamasregular';
    src: url('../fonts/bahamas-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/bahamas-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
          url('../fonts/bahamas-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
          url('../fonts/bahamas-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size:100%;
    }
@font-face {
    font-family: 'bahamaslightregular';
    src: url('../fonts/bahamaslight-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/bahamaslight-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
          url('../fonts/bahamaslight-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
          url('../fonts/bahamaslight-webfont.ttf') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size:100%;
    }
a {
    color:#369;
    }
a:hover {
    color:#000;
    background:#369;
    text-decoration:underline;
    }
h1, h2, h3 {
    color:#000;
    margin:.8em 0 .2em 0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: bahamasregular;
    }
p {
    color:#000;
    margin:.4em 0 .8em 0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: bahamaslightregular;
    }
.colmask {
    position:relative;
    clear:both;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
.col1 {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding:0 0 1em 0;
    overflow:hidden;
    }
.fullpage {
    min-height:1200px;
    }
.fullpage .col1 {
    width:96%;
    left:2%;
    }
img {
    max-width:100%;
    }
```

Here is my HTML5:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en-GB"><head>

    <title>Blaa blaa</title><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="description" content="Blaa blaa">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Blaa blaa">
    <meta name="robots" content="index, follow">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../resourses/css/mcontent.css" media="screen"></head>

<body onload="parent.resizeIframe(document.body.scrollHeight)">
    <div class="colmask fullpage">
        <div class="col1">
        <h1>Blaa blaa!</h1>
        <p>Blaa blaa foo blah bla.</p>
        <p>Blaa blaa foo blah bla!</p>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What on earth am I doing wrong?  Tested in IE 11, Firefox 28 and Comodo Dragon (by Comodo) on windows7.

Comment: Please fix the code in the question as suggested by @MF82, and *validate* your CSS code. Try to reduce the problem to a simpler case. E.g., is the `onload` attribute relevant? What do you see in Developer Tools—does the browser successfully load the font files? Regarding `h1`, note that it has by default `font-weight: bold` and you are specifying a normal font only in `@font-face`.

Comment: I edited the question, the onload is specific to an I frame, not its content or the css, so I can not see its relevance.  How and where do I validate my css code, what developer tools?  As to H1 default or not, the fonts do not show up at all, if it were just not in the expected way, is an entirely different question I could resolve when the need erises.

Comment: CSS Validator: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/. To enter developer tools, press key F12 key in a browser; take some time to learn to inspect elements, their style settings, and file loading (Network).

Comment: Jukka, I have only been doing this for a few months, with no prior experience what so ever, and even with an IQ above 170, my brain is not wired for this kind of thing.  I can build microwave spectrometers, light wave analyses systems and the like (you can find my work at Penn state, Washington state and other universities as well as at the Mayo clinic and other medical and major research facilities in the world), and I am a master guitar builder, I can fix everything on my car and house when needed, but coding just does not compute easily in my head. Sory.

Answer (score 0):

There too many brackets in your CSS code, which causes that the font-family isn't applied to any element or part of your webpage. And also, the quotes around the font-family are missing.

I think you should correct this part

```
h1, h2, h3 {
    color:#000;
    margin:.8em 0 .2em 0;
    padding:0;
    }
    {
    font-family: bahamasregular;
    }
```

to this

```
h1, h2, h3 {
    color:#000;
    margin:.8em 0 .2em 0;
    padding:0;
    font-family: 'bahamasregular';
}
```

There's the same mistake in your CSS code for the `p` element

Check also [this clear tutorial on @font-face](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/) for more info. Also, as Jukka pointed out, check if the font files are loading by using your browser's developer tools.

Comment: edited a bit. I think you were also missing quotes around the 'bahamasregular'....

Comment: Thanks MF82, but adding the Quotes does not solve the problem.  Although it raises more questions, because some things seem to work without them just fine, and in other cases they are absolutely needed, I do understand that double quotes must be used whenever spaces are in a path/file name.

Comment: Yes, I understood too that double quotes are used in case of spaces used in the font name. However the tutorial I'm referring is using single quotes in a similar as you have, since you also declared the font-name with single quotes. I'm still wondering whether your font files are actually loading. Did you check that?

Comment: I have found, but never used the developers tools, and will give them a try, but don't expect me to understand any of it any time soon.

Comment: What browser are you using? E.g. in Firefox, just hit F12 and go to the "Net" tab. Reload the page and keep that tab open. If any files are not found, you will see 404 errors ("not found" message).

Comment: I tried that too, but nothing happens, not even anything to indicate if Firefox is actually checking anything on page reload.

Comment: I poked around a little further, and found this: downloadable font: download failed (font-family: "bahamasregular" style:normal weight:normal stretch:normal src index:2): status=2147500037
source: file:///G:/Web%20Development/Experiments/Pre-site/resourses/fonts/bahamas-webfont.ttf  None of this is clear to me as to what it actually means.

Comment: since you are in the Netherlands, and most likely went to bed, I searched hi and low for answers, and found out that for some odd reasons the developers of Firefox restricted access to some (But not all) file type accessing in a way that makes little sense.  As to IE: it may have been the extra {} brackets, since after removing them it worked in IE.  I will now answer my own question, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, the problem was more than one problem:  Why it did not work in IE is not 100% clear to me since I tried a few solutions before testing with IE, but MF82 pointed out something that may have solved it in IE.  As for Firefox, it seems a lot of people have this problem.  This pertains to a local PC, not a server! Here is what worked for me:

In Firefox Local documents have access to other local documents in the same directory and in sub directories, but not directory listings.

The setting "security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy" in Firefox's prefs.js file is responsible, read this:  [MozillaZene's description](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy)

As far as I can tell it is not entirely correct since moving the font files into the same directory as the css file, and changing the path statements in the css file appropriately still did not work, but changing the setting did solve the problem.

Here is how to change the setting "security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy":  [Editing prefs.js in Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Editing_configuration) Double clicking the setting will change its value from "False" to "True".

The drawback is that you open up Your filesystem to be traversed, so I recommended You reverse the process, once You know everything works, and only change the setting when You need to see the fonts and then change it back again.  Maybe this will be fixed in a future version of Firefox.